# autoscroll with animate when cursor close to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make autoscroll when user cursor reach almost end of viewport.
I wrote the code below but it works only once, meaning the first time the user close to the bottom it autoscroll 300px down and stop.
how can I make it go down as long as the user is at the end of viewport?
and why it only works once?

```
$(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    var currposition = currentYPosition() + 800;
    var MouseY = event.clientY;
    if (MouseY > currposition-100) {
        //Down
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 300 // adjust number of px to scroll down
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: `scrollTop: '+=' + 300`, maybe? Can you create a snippet or bin?

Comment: tnx! it works!
do you know how can I make similar function for go UP case?

Comment: actually I see that it really go all the way down but if user move out from the bottom zone it keep do down...

Comment: Because `mousemove` fired many times (any pixel I think). Try to stop the animation when user move out from the zone. If you have more issues, please create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/) so it will much easier for us to help you.

Comment: You use function(e) but inside the function you use event.clientY. It is either both e or both event.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to scroll to top when mouse moved to top of screen?

Comment: sort of - just to start scroll up until user move the cursor from the top of the screen. and the opposite way when it at the bottom of the screen @Mohammad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple code

```js
$(".autoScrollBox").mousemove(function(e){
    var clientY = e.clientY;
    var boxHeight = $(this).height();
    var contentHeight = $(".autoScrollBox")[0].scrollHeight;
    var mousePositionProportion = clientY / boxHeight;
    var scrollTop = mousePositionProportion * (contentHeight - boxHeight);
    
    //// Top
    if (clientY < boxHeight / 2)
        scrollTop -= 50;
    //// Bottom
    else if (clientY > boxHeight - (boxHeight / 2))
        scrollTop += 50;
    
    $(".autoScrollBox").scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

```css
.autoScrollBox {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="autoScrollBox">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
    <p>18</p>
    <p>19</p>
    <p>20</p>
</div>
```

See better example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o59mwfp0/)

Comment: tnx! so if I change $(".autoScrollBox")  to $(window) it should work?

Comment: oh I see that $(window)[0].scrollHeight is undefined.. how can I make it return valid value?